# Try ... Catch doesn't catch Exception and still gives me runtime error

Tags: java, exception

I am doing a simple project, where the user inputs a should be double. However, professor wants the code to be idiot proof. So, I set up a try catch to catch exceptions that come out when the idiot enters something other than a double that doesn't fit. However, I still get runtime exceptions when I enter a String. Please help!

I have only tried the Try...Catch block, is there a way to either fix the block or is there another way to accomplish this?

```
try{
reapHeight = scanner.nextDouble();
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error : Invalid Input");
    System.out.print("Please try again : ");
    reapHeight = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

I want the

Error: Invalid Input 
Please try again:

To show up, but only a runtime exception occurs of InputMismatchException type.

Comment: You should use a while loop, because if the user fails the second time, the exception is not caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but only a runtime exception occurs of InputMismatchException type

because `nextDouble()` in the `try` block does not consume full user input including the new line char, so inside the `catch` block the 2nd `nextDouble()` throws the error which is uncaught. 
To avoid this you must use `nextLine()` after each call to `nextDouble()`.
Anyway your logic is wrong, because you must use a loop to get the user's input like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double reapHeight;
boolean valid = false;
do {
    try {
        reapHeight = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine();
        valid = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : Invalid Input");
        System.out.print("Please try again : ");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Scanner.nextLine()` after each `Scanner.nextDouble()`, and you need to remove the `Scanner.nextDouble()` from your `catch` block:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double reapHeight;
System.out.print("Enter a double: ");
while(true){
    try{
        reapHeight = in.nextDouble();
        break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Error : Invalid Input");
        System.out.print("Please try again : ");
    }
    finally{
        in.nextLine();
    }
}
```